# Can I both upvote and downvote a post for 8 reputation?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting

I see one answer, that was off topic (-1 vote) yet it was a good advice (+1 vote).

So 10 - 2 = 8 reputation should be given to that user or I don't know how to take care of that. But I always see this situation.

So I left this topic for discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach I have seen used with good results is to leave a comment to the person answering explaining why their answer is off topic and any suggestions you may have as to bringing it more on point. The communal nature of SO is great in that several people can collaborate together to take bits and pieces of genius to form one coherent critical mass of genius.

So instead of having this moral dilemma with yourself over whether to vote up or down, perhaps engage the individual and coach them into providing a better answer for the community.